# filter mapping to last path segment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml, servlet-filters, servlet-mapping

I am trying to map a filter to a specific url in web.xml. The problem is that there is a dynamic path segment in the url and I need to map my filter only to URLs ending with a specific path. For given URLs:

```
http://company.com/webApp/aaa/end
http://company.com/webApp/bbb/end
http://company.com/webApp/ccc/end
```

I need to map a servlet like:

```
<filter id="EndFilter">
    <filter-name>EndFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.EndFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EndFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*/end</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

I know that */ is not a valid wildcard but I dont know if this type of mapping is even possible. It is easy to map URLs with resources like pictures with endings *.png or *.jpeg wildcard but i can't find a way to map a simple url path segment.

Comment: Those are filter mappings. Are you talking about filters or servlets?

Comment: I mean filters, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [servlet 3.1 specification chapter 12](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html):

> In the Web application deployment descriptor
>   , the following syntax is used to define 
>   mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string (`""`) is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form http://host:port/. In this case the path info is `/` and the servlet path and context path is empty string (`""`).
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So it looks like it is not possible.